# XML SDMX reading in python

Tags: python, xml, sdmx

Im strugling to read SDMX XML file with python from below links:
https://www.newyorkfed.org/xml/fedfunds.html or
[direct](https://websvcgatewayx2.frbny.org/autorates_fedfunds_external/services/v1_0/fedfunds/xml/retrieve?typ=RATE&f=03012016&t=04032020)

Ideally i would like to get fund rates into dataframe but i was trying to use pandasdmx which doesnt seem to work with this one

My Current code:
f

```
rom urllib.request import urlopen
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = "https://websvcgatewayx2.frbny.org/autorates_fedfunds_external/services/v1_0/fedfunds/xml/retrieve?typ=RATE&f=03012016&t=04032020"

d2 = urlopen(url).read()
root  ET.fromstring(d2)

for elem in root.iter():
    k = elem.get('OBS_VALUE')
    if k is not None:
        print(k)
```

I would like to get something that will look like this:

```
             FUNDRATE_OBS_POINT='1%' FUNDRATE_OBS_POINT='25%'
2020-04-02   0.03                    0.05
2020-04-01   0.03                    0.05
2020-04-01   0.01                    0.05
```

I found this method to be pretty ugly, and for each "data" i need to check if its not None. Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: Can you edit and provide a short example of what the dataframe will look like?

Comment: something like this. where different FUNDRATE_OBS_POINT would be columns, dates as index and OBS_VALUE as respective column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
from lxml import etree
import requests

resp = requests.get(url)

doc = etree.fromstring(resp.content)

headers = []
dates = []
columns = []

fop = doc.xpath('//Series[@FUNDRATE_OBS_POINT]')
datpath = fop[0].xpath('//*[@*="ns13:ObsType"]')
for dat in datpath:
    dates.append(dat.attrib.get('TIME_PERIOD'))
for item in fop:
    headers.append(item.attrib.get('FUNDRATE_OBS_POINT'))
    entries = item.xpath('//*[@*="ns13:ObsType"]')
    column = []
    for entry in entries:
        column.append(entry.attrib.get('OBS_VALUE'))
    columns.append(column)


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=headers,index=dates)

for a, b in zip(headers,columns):
    df[a] = b
df.head(3)
```

Output:

```
             1%     25%     50%     75%     99%  TARGET_HIGH  TARGET_LOW
2020-04-02  0.03    0.03    0.03    0.03    0.03    0.03    0.03
2020-04-01  0.03    0.03    0.03    0.03    0.03    0.03    0.03
2020-03-31  0.01    0.01    0.01    0.01    0.01    0.01    0.01
```